# Laravel query where a column must have specified multiple variable

Tags: php, laravel

I dont know how to describe this problem. Lets say i have this table in my database:

```
| Team | Zone |
| ---- | ---- |
| Alfa | A    |
| Alfa | BB   |
| Alfa | CCC  |
| Beta | A    |
| Beta | CCC  |
| Beta | DDDD |
| Crit | BB   |
| Crit | CCC  |
```

And then I make some form in my view, that can search the team name based on zone. The form looks like this
[image]

What i wanted are:

- If i enter 'A' and 'CCC' in the said form, it will show team Alfa and Beta
- If i enter 'BB' and 'CCC' in the said form, it will show team Alfa and Crit
- If i enter only 'BB' in the said form, it will show team Alfa and Crit

The problem is, i haven't figured out the query or the code to get that result. I have tried the following code:

```
$find = DB::table('team_zone_area')->select(
    'team'
);
        
if(isset($req->search_zones)){
    $find = $find->where('zone', $req->search_zones[0]);

    if(count($req->search_zones) > 1){
        for($j = 1; $j < count($req->search_zones); $j++){
            $find = $find->where('zone', $req->search_zones[$j]);
        }
    }
}

$find = $find->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->groupBy('team')
        ->get();
```

It show zero result if i search for zone 'A' and 'CCC', or 'BB' and 'CCC', but it will show correct team if i just enter zone 'BB'

Then i tried to tweak the code `if(count($req->search_zones) > 1)` into this:

```
if(count($req->search_zones) > 1){
    for($j = 1; $j < count($req->search_zones); $j++){
        $find = $find->orWhere('zone', $req->search_zones[$j]);
    }
}
```

Now it shows all teams (Alfa, Beta, Crit) when i enter 'A' and 'CCC', instead of just Alfa and Beta

Anyone have idea what the query supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
$zones = ['A', 'CCC']; # should be array `$request->zones`

$query = DB::table('team_zone_area')
    ->select('team')
    ->whereIn('zone', $zones) # use `whereIn`
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->groupBy('team')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT zone) = ?', [count($zones)]) #make sure this is not empty
    ->get();
```

Comment: It works, but how? I tried using only `whereIn` but it give the same result as `orWhere`. After i give the `havingRaw` like your answer, it works as intended

Comment: `...Raw` is used to run raw SQL queries.

Comment: I mean, the `COUNT(DISTINCT zone)` and the parameter `[count($zones)]`, what do they do?

Comment: There is nothing complex there—just standard SQL and PHP functions. Search `MySQL Count`, `MySQL DISTINCT`  and PHP `Count`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `whereIn` query instead of a regular one:

```php
$find = DB::table('team_zone_area')
    ->select('team');
        
if(isset($req->search_zones)){
    $find = $find->whereIn('zone', $req->search_zones);
}

//Aditional you don't need the groupBy clause if you just need the team
$find = $find
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->get();
```